# How do I disable the next button if Angular reactive form is untouched?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on an Angular quiz app and would like to disable the Next button if the form is untouched (basically before the user selects an option). The next button is in a different component than the form. It seems that the problem is with communication between the components. Please see my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-quiz-app

I'm also having some trouble with clearing of the form. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form. You can check your `formGroup` for the [touched](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#touched) status.

Comment: Please ask a different question for the other question or consult the angular documentation. There are more methods you can make use off to reset your data.

Comment: This question has more to do with component-component communication than with Reactive Forms.
AFAICT, the problem is that you need to know in a parent component if the form in a child component is touched or not.

You can simply add an `@Output()` with the touched event or expose directly the FormGroup (which wouldn't be extra clean, but possibly just fine)

Comment: Yes the problem is with communication. I've added @Output() to formGroup in my child (form) component and @Input() to formGroup() in my parent component, but still somehow the communication isn't working as I've also added this.formGroup.reset({answer: null}) in my parent but this isn't working.

Comment: added [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" to my next button but am getting the error in the console that "Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined"